# Filtering and formatting XML in node.js

Tags: node.js, xml

I am looking to filter and format an XML file from the filesystem and send the result back to the client that requested it.

The XML looks like this:

```xml
<root>
<menu>
<date>12.21.2000</date>
 <dishes>
  <dish>fries with ketchup</dish>
  <dish>salad</dish>
 </dishes>
</menu>
<menu>
 <date>12.21.2000</date>
 <dishes>
  <dish>fries with ketchup</dish>
  <dish>salad</dish>
 </dishes>
</menu>
...
</root>
```

And I want to return them like this after filtering for a certain number of dishes and a Date.

```xml
<menu>
 <date>12.21.2000</date>
 <numberofdishes>2</numberofdishes>
</menu>
```

In my approach I converted them to JSON first and did all the logic on that, then converted back using xml2js(a npm package), but that feels very inefficient and quite wrong to do.

What is the recommended way to work on xml in node?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple XSLT transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
expand-text="yes">

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

<xsl:template match="menu">
  <menu>
    <xsl:copy-of select="date"/>
    <numberOfDishes>{count(dishes/dish)}</numberOfDishes>
  </menu>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT 3.0 is available in node.js through the Saxon-JS library which you can download from npm. (This transformation is so simple it doesn't actually need any XSLT 3.0 features, but you might as well use it since it's there.)

I'm not quite sure of the exact transformation rules you want to apply (e.g. why there are two menus in your input but only one in the output) but that shouldn't be a problem.

[Disclaimer: Saxon-JS is my company's product]